# Proper timing for submitting a paper

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Is there any general advise on when better to submit a paper?

I mean, should one consider the seasonal differences in the way journals work.

Let's say, I have a manuscript ready to submit at the beginning of June. Would it make any sense to withhold it until the beginning of the new academic year as there is low chance the paper would be proceeded during the summer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the best solution would be to consult with other colleagues who sent to that journal before.

However, IMHO I don't think that submitting in summer would be like what you stated; the review process may be delayed a little bit however that does not mean that the reviewing process is stopped during summer.

Answer (score 6):

You should submit it once you finished. You should not wait or think about for new academic year. This is your misconception to have less chance to publish in summer. Because all the manuscripts goes under review process which takes usually 2-3 months and then it will be decided for next step.